# permit params by JSON Rails

Tags: json, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5, restful-url

I have a problem when trying to validate params in Rails, I want to post data by POST but I neet to validate first the structure of the Json object.

this is my JSON:

```
{"car":{"year": 2018, "owner": "Fernando"}}
```

I do not want to keep the value as null.

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:model, :year)
end
```

I need to throw and error if in the JSON structure exists for example the owner field.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Strong parameters exist exactly to perform this job. If you do not include `owner` on permitted params and try to save your object with this params, the model will throw an exception. The question is, why you want to "double-check" this behavior?

Comment: I just want to return a 400 error if a json structure is not correct, I don't want to keep that value null, I want to deny the post.
greetings.

Comment: the problem is that the model is not throwing anything it is saving the object to the db but the field owner is saved as nil, I don't want to do that just throw a 400, please if someone could help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the owner field is present and raise the error for example...

```
def car_params
  raise StandardError.new('Invalid JSON structure.') if params[:car].key?(:owner)
  params.require(:car).permit(:model, :year)
end
```

Is that what you had in your mind? I'm not sure if I got your point.

Comment: not really, I want to deny access to everything different to  model or year not just owner.

Thank you so much for your answer, greetings.